# Instantiation and Property Setting in 1 go

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How does this evaluate, like, whats the flow,

This:

```
var tag = new TagBuilder("a");
tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
```

Can be turned into this:

```
var tag = new TagBuilder("a")
{
    MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i)),
    InnerHtml = i.ToString()
};
```

Does it go:

1. Instastiates new object
2. Parses the argument and sets it up
3. Assigns all the values to the properties

Effectively does it mean the same thing, why and how?

Even if there was no `"a"` being parsed, would it still instantiate the object and give all the property values their defaults?

Comment: It is just the syntactic sugar, provided by compiler. result is 100% the same.

Comment: Your second snippet won't compile, you can't call a method from object initializer. And I have no idea why are you talking about “parsing”, C# is not an interpreted language.

Comment: kk thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in §7.6.10.2 Object initializers of the specification. Quoting an example from there that explains how is object initializer compiled:

> The following class represents a point with two coordinates:
>
> ```
> public class Point
> {
>    int x, y;
>
>    public int X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
>    public int Y { get { return y; } set { y = value; } }
> }
> ```
>
> An instance of `Point` can be created and initialized as follows:
>
> ```
> Point a = new Point { X = 0, Y = 1 };
> ```
>
> which has the same effect as
>
> ```
> Point __a = new Point();
> __a.X = 0;
> __a.Y = 1;
> Point a = __a;
> ```
>
> where `__a` is an otherwise invisible and inaccessible temporary
>   variable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot call a method in an object initializer. So you may have this:

```
var tag = new TagBuilder("a")
{
    // MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i)), you can not do this
    InnerHtml = i.ToString()
};
```

As @RadimKohler said, this is a syntactic sugar, provided by compiler. You write codes like this, and at compile time, the compiler will do the rest. So, the compiler generated code, for your example is:

```
TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
// the rest of your code...
```